# Hide element when another element is present on the page

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I want to hide an element if one element is already present on the page.

If element with the id:

```
#wcfmmp_store_about
```

is present on the page, then hide following element:

```
.left_sidebar.widget-area.sidebar
```

I want to achieve is either through a function or .css, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Okay, so what's the problem? CSS lets you do this just fine, what is the DOM relation between those two (e.g. are they ancestor/descendent? different parts of the DOM tree?) and what CSS did you already try for that relation?

Comment: When is this supposed to happen? Only on page load? Or can a user trigger this change by some action?

Comment: Yes, only on page load.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans they don't have the relation, they are just part of the page body #main

Comment: Here's the html page:https://gigrove-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/content/uploads/2020/11/22221108/Comida-Hawaiana.html I want to disable sidebar on the left when "About" area is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it with JavaScript.

```
var element = document.getElementById('wcfmmp_store_about');

if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null)
{
 document.querySelector('.left_sidebar').classList.add("sidebar_hidden");
} else {
 document.querySelector('.left_sidebar').classList.remove("sidebar_hidden");
}
```

```
.left_sidebar.sidebar_hidden {
  display: none 
}
```

Comment: Please give an example of how your DOM is structured.

Comment: Here's the html page: https://gigrove-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/content/uploads/2020/11/22221108/Comida-Hawaiana.html
I want to disable sidebar on the left when "About" area is active.

Comment: I need a solution that will work sitewise as this is a template. I cannot add code to each page.

Comment: There are multiple errors in the code you've added to your page. In `document.getElementById('#wcfmmp_store_about');`, you have to remove the **#**. Please copy and paste it exactly like it is in my example. Secondly, you've added the code to the head section of your page. Make sure that the code is at the very bottom of the page so that the code has access to the complete DOM.

Comment: Could you please tell me if I want to hide based on the #policy element along with the #wcfmmp_store_about. What do I need to change in your code?

Comment: Don't manipulate `.style` directly, set a class using `.classList.add("...")` and `.classList.remove("...")`, and have that class set the "display: none" rule, so that CSS can keep working the way it's supposed to.